# Is there a way to move the calendar of a datePicker in spinner mode?

Tags: android, datepicker, calendar, spinner

[image: What I want to do]

I'm looking for something like this. I have plenty of vertical screen real estate, and I like how the calendar fits in with the app, but I want the user to have a spinner for the year as well. I just want to know if there's a way to move the calendar (if that's possible) so that the year spinner would be able to be seen.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the pickerMode to your DatePicker in your XML file:

```
<DatePicker
...
android:datePickerMode="spinner" />
```

Comment: I already have it in spinner mode. I'm asking if there's a way to move the calendar underneath so that I can show the year spinner.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can add a popup dialog which is more customizable. If you use a popupdialog, then you have to handle more cases compared to spinner.

And in onclick event of the view, attach popupwindow

```
   PopupWindow yourDatePopup = datePopupWindow();
   //this line will give a spinner effect
   yourDatePopup.showAsDropDown(clickableView, -7, 0);

   public PopupWindow datePopupWindow() {

    PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(this);
    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
    popupWindow.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popupWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    // set the list view as pop up window content
    //Define your dateview
    popupWindow.setContentView(yourDateView);
    popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    return popupWindow;
  }
```

Note:- Just to help, not exact code